pass sqlRestriction into criteria - bad sql grammar
So I want to add a sqlRestriction in my criteria because my data field needs to be trimmed before I want to check it.
I tried adding it in my existing filter like this
public List<FooBarZ> findByFilter(Filter filter) {
 DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(getPersistentClass());
 String alias = getAlias(criteria); // outputs "this."
    
 criteria.add(eq(alias + "foo", filter.getFoo());
 criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trim(" + alias + "bar) like %" + filter.getBar()));
    
return findByCriteria(criteria, 0, filter.getMaxRows());
}

so my criterionEntries look like this
criteria>criteria>criterionEntries=
this.foo=1
trim(this.bar) like %2

now If this query gets run (Hibernate) I get my bad sql grammar error
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; bad SQL grammar
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown token:  in statement[
    select
        this_.IDFOO as IDFOO,
        this_.IDBAR as IDBAR
    from
        TABLE this_
        where trim(this.bar) like %2
]


So I can see why the syntax is wrong but I dont understand why.
Why is my this.field not correctly mapped to the db field?
Why is this where shown and not the previous one?
how to fix this?
ELI5:
have data in my db that contains whitespace which i need to be removed before I can filter
so my filter X should match dbvalue '0X       ' (char(9))
My filter works perfectly fine without this trim one but I want to add this.

Answer:
sqlRestriction should directly use {alias}.COLUMNNAME
so
 criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trim(" + alias + "bar) like %" + filter.getBar()));

becomes
 criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
                    "trim({alias}.IDBAR) like ?",
                    "%" + filter.getBar(),
                    Hibernate.STRING
            ));


The LIKE expression has the format string LIKE pattern, where pattern must be a string literal. In SQL, string literals must be enclosed in single quotes. So you would use something like
"trim(" + alias + "bar) like '%" + filter.getBar() + "'"

to get
where trim(this.bar) like '%2'

